# add an element with value to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this code with missing part and the output:

```
<?php
$months = array('four'=>'April', 'five'=>'May');
Missing#6;
Missing#7;
echo $months['nine']."<br>";
echo $months['ten'];
?>
```

The output:

**September

October**

and since it has two lines missing, I tried doing

```
<?php
$months = array('four'=>'April', 'five'=>'May');
$months[] = array('nine'=>'september');
$months = array('ten'=>'october');
echo $months['nine'], "\n";
echo $months['ten'];
?>
```

but in the compiler only print October and an error for nine:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nine in 1784341836/source.php on line 5

Comment: You are missing the square brackets after $months on the line that assigns ten => October

Answer (score 2):

You can add values with associated keys by accessing the array at that key and assigning the value.

```
<?php
$months = array('four'=>'April', 'five'=>'May');
$months['nine'] = 'September';
$months['ten'] = 'October';
echo $months['nine'], "\n";
echo $months['ten'];
?>
```

This will return:

September

October